# Does ReactNative actual height includes border and padding？

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]
As you can see:

```
style={{
          width:100,
          height: 30,
          borderWidth:1,
          paddingTop:100
             }}
```

The expected size is to be 100*132.

However it is 100*102 which height of 102 is made up of paddingTop and borderWidth.

Does this have something to do with element type like inline or block type?

Answer (score 0):

In react native, `borderWidth` is included in the `height` and `width` properties in normal Views. If you desire 100*100 box with borders, do:

```
style={{
          width:100,
          height: 100,
          borderWidth:1,
     }}
```

Back to your question brother, YES `TextInput`'s actual height includes `border` and `padding`. Therefore, the whole height of your `TextInput` is taken up by the `paddingTop` property which extends to 100. Since the `height` property is no longer significant in your `TextInput`, `borderWidth` and `paddingTop` values are taken as they are.
Therefore the solution would be to make sure that the `padding` space/value does not exceed the `height`.